# Relation between a linear equation system and a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, linear-transformations, algebraic-graph-theory

Consider a linear equation system
$$ \sum_{j \in J} A_{i,j}.x_{j}=b_{i},\ \ \ \          \forall i\in I. $$

Consider the graph $G(I \cup J,S)$, where $S=\lbrace s:A_{i,j} \ne 0\rbrace  $.

What type of information about the solutions to the system can be learned from this graph ?

What properties of this graph do the usual *factorization* or *elimination* procedures change ?

Comment: Think connected components

Comment: Yes, I know from intuition and simple cases that connectivity is important, but is there any formal result I can look into ?